# using a single line to filter out digits from string python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am refactoring my code so that it is done in a more pythonic way. Specifically I have a section 
that is returning tokens from a string if that token is not an integer. Initially I wrote the function as follows

```
 string = "these 5 sentences should not have 2 numbers in them"
 newString = []
 for token in string.split():
     if token.isdigit() == False:
         newString.append(token)
 newString = " ".join(newString)
 print(newString)
```

While this works I wont to make the code look less clunky. So I rewrote it as follows

```
   newString = [token for token in string.split() if token is not 
   token.isdigit() ]
```

But this does not seem to catch the digits. Why is the lambda expression not working ?

Comment: `newString = " ".join(i for i in string.split() if not i.isdigit())` ?

Comment: `is not token.isdigit()` is saying "if the item in the string is not the same object as the Boolean returned from this check" rather than using the Bool as a filter

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```py
string = "these 5 sentences should not have 2 numbers in them"

newString = " ".join(token for token in string.split() if not token.isdigit())

print(newString)
```

the problem was the use of `is`.

although python is very similar to English sometimes, which is great, in some cases it causes confusion :)

[`is` is an identity comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is),

quoting the docs:

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: `x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the id() function. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

it tried to see if `token` (which is some string) is not `token.isdigit()` (which is some boolean), this is of course true for all tokens :)

Comment: Not exactly equality operator, but close enough: `>>> a = numpy.zeros([1,1])`
`>>> b = numpy.zeros([1,1])`
`>>> a == b    
array([[ True]])`
`>>> a is b    
False`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are comparing `token` and `token.isdigit()` with `is not` operator. It compares objects if they are the same object, but `string` and `boolean` are not even the same type, so outcome is always true:

```
>>> string = "these 5 sentences should not have 2 numbers in them"
>>> string.split()
['these', '5', 'sentences', 'should', 'not', 'have', '2', 'numbers', 'in', 'them']
>>> token = string.split()[3]
>>> token
'should'
>>> token.isdigit()
False
>>> token is not token.isdigit()
True
>>> token = string.split()[1]
>>> token
'5'
>>> token is not token.isdigit()
True
```

So you should just drop `token is` from your code and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working, I just tried it.

```
newString = " ".join([x for x in string.split() if x.isdigit() == False])
```

Check it.

All things in one line of code only.

Comment: The code will work because it's based on the principles already discussed by other answers before yours. There is no need for `== False`

Comment: Yes that's true, but I tried to make it as simple as it can be to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
newstring = ''.join(map(lambda x: x if not x.isdigit() else "", string.split() ))
```

exactly with spaces:

```
newstring = ' '.join(map(lambda x: x if not x.isdigit() else "", string.split() )).replace('  ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `filter()`, perhaps slightly shorter:

`newString = ' '.join(filter(lambda s: not s.isdigit(), string.split()))`